# How to implement a non-trivial map between collections in Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, f#, system.reactive

I would like to implement a **map from selected objects** to **property entries** in property editor. For example like in Visual Studio xaml editor.

The target map is something like this (or maybe using ReactiveCollection from ReactiveUI?)

```
 Selected objects             Filled categories to display in PropertyEditor  
 -------------------------    ---------------------------------------
 ObservableCollection<obj> -> ObservableCollection<Category>
```

The map in plain English:

1. Collect all unique property types from objects
2. Group by category (e.g. Text, Layout)
3. Add/Remove categories as necessary to reflect selected objects
4. Add/Remove properties from existing categories as necessary

The challenge is to have declarative/functional code without add/remove branches. (I do already have an imperative/event based code which is quite ugly and error prone.)

I think we could assume that Category and Property collections are sets with the usual operations: Union, Substract, and IsMember.

The inspiration is the code from [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/) by Paul Betts which is beatiful for simple one-to-one map:

```cs
var Models = new ReactiveCollection<ModelClass>();
var ViewModels = Models.CreateDerivedCollection(x => new ViewModelForModelClass(x));
// Now, adding / removing Models means we
// automatically have a corresponding ViewModel
Models.Add(new Model(”Hello!”));
ViewModels.Count();
>>> 1
```

Using Seq and F# the straightforward nonobservable map would look like this:

```ml
selectedObjects
|> Seq.collect GetProperties |> Seq.unique |> Seq.groupBy GetPropertyCategory
|> Seq.map (fun categoryName properies -> CreateCategory(properties))
```

The above code is fine in theory but in practice it would recreate all the view models from scratch on each change in selected objects. What I would love to achieve with Rex is to have the version of the above map **with incremental updates**, so the WPF will update only the changed parts of the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem :-). Sadly, I don't think there is any F# library that allows you to solve that easily. As far as I can tell, [Bindable LINQ](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/) was one attempt to implement LINQ query pattern (i.e. `Select`, `SelectMany` and `Where` methods) for `ObservableCollection<T>`, which is essentially what you need. To use it from F#, you could wrap LINQ operations in functions like `map` etc.

As you say, functions like `Seq.map` work by on `IEnumerable` and so they are not incremental. What you'd need here are functions like `map`, `filter` and `collect`, but implemented over `ObservableCollection<'T>` in such a way that they do the changes incrementally - when new element is added to the source collection, the `map` function would process it and add a new element to the resulting collection.

I experimented with that a bit and here is an implementation of `map` that is incremental:

```ml
open System.Collections.Specialized
open System.Collections.ObjectModel

module ObservableCollection =
  /// Initialize observable collection
  let init n f = ObservableCollection<_>(List.init n f)

  /// Incremental map for observable collections
  let map f (oc:ObservableCollection<'T>) =
    // Create a resulting collection based on current elements
    let res = ObservableCollection<_>(Seq.map f oc)
    // Watch for changes in the source collection
    oc.CollectionChanged.Add(fun change ->
      printfn "%A" change.Action
      match change.Action with
      | NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add ->
          // Apply 'f' to all new elements and add them to the result
          change.NewItems |> Seq.cast<'T> |> Seq.iteri (fun index item ->
            res.Insert(change.NewStartingIndex + index, f item))
      | NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move ->
          // Move element in the resulting collection
          res.Move(change.OldStartingIndex, change.NewStartingIndex)
      | NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove ->
          // Remove element in the result
          res.RemoveAt(change.OldStartingIndex)
      | NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace -> 
          // Replace element with a new one (processed using 'f')
          change.NewItems |> Seq.cast<'T> |> Seq.iteri (fun index item ->
            res.[change.NewStartingIndex + index] <- f item)
      | NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset ->
          // Clear everything
          res.Clear()
      | _ -> failwith "Unexpected action!" )
    res
```

Implementing `map` was quite easy, but I'm afraid that functions like `collect` and `groupBy` will be quite tricky. Anyway, here is a sample showing how you can use it:

```ml
let src = ObservableCollection.init 5 (fun n -> n)
let res = ObservableCollection.map (fun x -> printfn "processing %d" x; x * 10) src

src.Move(0, 1)
src.Remove(0)
src.Clear()
src.Add(5)
src.Insert(0, 3)
src.[0] <- 1

// Compare the original and the result
printfn "%A" (Seq.zip src res |> List.ofSeq)
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas! Now I am developing it in a small library. For example: map : ('T -> 'A) -> RxSeq<'T> -> RxSeq<'A> where type RxSeq<'T> = IObservableWithState<RxSeqUpdate<'T>, ObservableCollection<'T>>

Comment: @Alfa07 Nice! Are you going to share the library somewhere? If so, perhaps I could contribute a few more functions.

Comment: Yes, sure! It would be great! As soon as I get in reasonable shape I will share it and send the link to you.